# how to raise/rescue from ActionMailer deliver method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am sending emails with the following method:

```
class Communicate < ActionMailer::Base
  def message(sub,msg,people)
    subject    sub
    bcc        people
    from       'my_email.s@gmail.com'
    sent_on    Time.now

    body       :greeting => msg
  end
end
```

bcc contains 4 or 5 email addresses.

During my testing I've noticed two things:

- That if even one of the emails is not an actual email (for example `fake_email_no_domain`) it does not send emails to any of the recipients
- if the bcc list has a bad email address (for example `nonexistent@gmail.com`) then it still sends emails to other recipients but still throws an error to the logs.

In both scenarios the error that is thrown is:

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed in 2601ms (DB: 1) | 302 Found [http://localhost/notifications]

    [2010-08-04 00:49:00] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer
        /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:56:in `eof?'
        /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:56:in `run'
        /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

**Questions:**

- Is there any way I can catch this error? I am showing a `flash[:notice]` to the user and i'd like to mention that something bad happened
- If my BCC list has 5 emails and really only 4 emails are sent because 5th was nonexistent email then after all is done can I get a number of how many emails were actually sent?  I'd like to show that number in my `flash[:notice]`.  I can get this number by actually calling the delivery method in a iteration rather then sending as bulk but still I would not want to increment the count if one email is not sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add or uncomment following line in the `config/environments/development.rb`   and restart your server.

```
# Don't care if the mailer can't send
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
```

I assume you check for the `development` for `production` add line in `config/environments/production.rb`

Comment: I had that line in development.rb but removing that has no effect.  Still that same error is thrown.

Comment: sorry it's my mistake `Add or uncomment` that line don't remove also don't forget to restart your server.

Comment: I've added it `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false` but now it does not even throw errors to the log that it was throwing before...

Comment: Why is this answer accepted? I think it simply hides the error, by not raising anymore, but emails still won't be delivered, and specifically, there is no notification to the user, which was asked for in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I am writing the code to sent the email in controller i can write like these to handle the rescue in my application
 I'm using something like this in the controller:

```
if @user.save
  begin
  UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
  flash[:success] = "#{@user.name} created"
  rescue Net::SMTPAuthenticationError, Net::SMTPServerBusy, Net::SMTPSyntaxError, Net::SMTPFatalError, Net::SMTPUnknownError => e
  flash[:success] = "User #{@user.name} creating Problems sending mail"
  end
  redirect_to home_index_path
end
```